# Grok filter for logstash to match a specific value from a log file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have the following log:

```
2018-10-30 11:47:52 INFO     30464 SMS-MT [cid:300038] [queue-msgid:bb7a195d-fb23-42ae-bbfa-d2dcda405af9] [smpp-msgid:j.11082.639364178944.#MARKET SETU] [status:ESME_ROK] [prio:1] [dlr:NO_SMSC_DELIVERY_RECEIPT_REQUESTED] [validity:none] [from:2323232] [to:23232132312] [content:'#MARKET SETUP\nadsadadadadasdasdadaasdada mo ang:\nC jean_rivera\n--Mag reply ng A-C']
```

I've created a grok filter based on pattern in logstash so I can parse the log the way I want. And I have this:

```
%{DATESTAMP:Timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:Level}     %{BASE10NUM:Pid} %{USERNAME:SMS_TYPE} %{CID:CID} %{GREEDYDATA:Message}
```

I'm trying to create a GROK patter that will match **300038**, which is the number coming after cid:. The syntax is always the same, [cid:number]. What I have now is:

```
    CID (\[cid:[0-9]{6}\])
but that results into: 
"CID": [
    [
      "[cid:300038]"
    ]
  ],
```

and I only want to match the 300038, without the **[cid:] part**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that there are more than single space character between `LOG` and `pid`, you can match all of them using `\s*`.

To match just a number from `[cid:300038]` you can use [custom pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns), `\[cid:(?<CID>[0-9]{1,})\]` this will match `cid` of any length, not just 6 digits.

Your pattern will become,

```
%{DATESTAMP:Timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:Level}\s*%{BASE10NUM:Pid} %{USERNAME:SMS_TYPE} \[cid:(?<CID>[0-9]{1,})\] %{GREEDYDATA:Message}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected. Since both answers seems to do the same thing I will chose this one though since as far as I know cid could be any length from 3 to whatever, probably not more than 10 in our case but it's better to match it like this

Comment: I ended up using this: `%{DATESTAMP:Timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:Level}\s*%{BASE10NUM:Pid} %{USERNAME:SMS_TYPE} \[cid:(?<CID>[0-9]{1,})\] \[queue-msgid:(?<queue_id>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)\] %{DATA:smpp} \[from:(?<from>[0-9]{1,})\] \[to:(?<to>[0-9]{1,})\] %{GREEDYDATA:Message}`

Comment: It would be also nice if I can create a grok pattern similar to the above and use like  %{CID:cid} instead of using the full syntax in the line... Any ideea how to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by `using the full syntax`?

Comment: What I means is to define a grok pattern, then call it. Same as I did for pid or SMS_TYPE, Level etc

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
%{DATESTAMP:Timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:Level}     %{BASE10NUM:Pid} %{USERNAME:SMS_TYPE} \[cid:(?<CID>[0-9]{6})\] %{GREEDYDATA:Message}
```